# Common Lisp: Best method to temporarily import a few functions from a package

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to temporarily import a few functions from a package into the current package, using standard common-lisp functions/macros?

I couldn't find one and had to roll my own. I'd rather not have to code anything up, or introduce another language construct, if the standard already provides such functionality.

```
(defmacro with-functions (functions the-package &body body)
  "Allows functions in the-package to be visible only for body.
  Does this by creating local lexical function bindings that redirect calls
  to functions defined in the-package"
  `(labels
     ,(mapcar (lambda (x) `(,x (&rest args)
                               (apply (find-symbol ,(format nil "~:@(~a~)" x) 
                                                   ,the-package)
                                      args)))
              functions)
     ,@body))
```

Example usage:

```
(defclass-default test-class ()
  ((a 5 "doc" )
   (b 4 "doc")))
#<STANDARD-CLASS TEST-CLASS>
CL-USER> 
(with-functions (class-direct-slots slot-definition-name) 'sb-mop
  (with-functions (slot-definition-initform) 'sb-mop
    (slot-definition-initform
      (car (class-direct-slots (find-class 'test-class))))))
5
CL-USER>
```

EDIT: Incorporated some of Rainer's suggestions to the macro.

I decided to keep the run-time lookup capability, at the time cost of the run-time lookup to find the function in the package.

I tried to write a with-import macro that used shadowing-import and unintern, but I couldn't get it to work. I had issues with the reader saying that the imported functions didn't exist yet (at read time) before the code that imported the functions was evaluated.

I think getting it to work with shadowing-import and unintern is a better way to go, as this would be much cleaner, faster (no run-time lookup capability though) and work with functions and symbols in packages.

I would be very interested to see if someone can code up a with-import macro using unintern and shadowing-import.

Comment: This does not work with lexical functions, since APPLY can't call them using symbols as names.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a macro, because symbols are resolved by the reader before macro are expanded, but I might be wrong I don't fully understand yet how the reader works.

Comment: @Daimrod It should be possible to construct such a macro, but it is very tricky (and, probably, unportable), because you will have to handle name conflicts, arising from the early symbol-resolution strategy.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin: Ok, but I think it could be done with a reader macro and a code walker but that's sounds like a lot of work for a small improvement to me.

Comment: Might it be a better solution for what you're trying to do to switch packages multiple times in the source file?

Comment: @claytontstanley: one obvious problem caused by the design is that you can't nest it.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I can't figure out what you mean by 'can't nest it'; If you have time, could you provide a use case that doesn't work? I can then use that to fix the design.

Answer (score 2):

It makes runtime function calls much more costly: it conses an arg list, looks up a symbol in a package, calls a function through the symbol's function cell.

It only works through symbols, not lexical functions. That makes it less useful in cases, where code is generated via macros.

Its naming is confusing. 'import' is a package operation and packages deal only with symbols, not functions. You can't import a function in a package, only a symbol.

```
(labels ((foo () 'bar))
  (foo))
```

The lexical function name `FOO` is only in the source code a symbol. There is no way to access the function through its source symbol later (for example by using `(symbol-function 'foo)`). If a compiler will compile above code, it does not need to keep the symbol - it is not needed other than for debugging purposes. Your call to APPLY will fail to find any function created by LABELS or FLET.

Your macro does not import a symbol, it creates a local lexical function binding.

For slightly similar macros see `CL:WITH-SLOTS` and `CL:WITH-ACCESSORS`. Those don't support runtime lookup, but allow efficient compilation.

Your macro does not nest like this (here using "CLOS" as a package, just like your "SB-MOP"):

```
(defpackage "P1" (:use "CL"))
(defpackage "P2" (:use "CL"))

(with-import (p1::class-direct-slots) 'CLOS
  (with-import (p2::class-direct-slots) 'P1
    (p2::class-direct-slots (find-class 'test-class))))
```

The generated code is:

```
(LABELS ((P1::CLASS-DIRECT-SLOTS (&REST ARGS)
           (APPLY (FIND-SYMBOL "CLASS-DIRECT-SLOTS" 'CLOS) ARGS)))
  (LABELS ((P2::CLASS-DIRECT-SLOTS (&REST ARGS)
             (APPLY (FIND-SYMBOL "CLASS-DIRECT-SLOTS" 'P1) ARGS)))
    (P2::CLASS-DIRECT-SLOTS (FIND-CLASS 'TEST-CLASS))))
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your use case. There shouldn't be any ':'s in the 'functions' arglist. The functions arglist has the symbols that represent the function names, and the-package is where those functions reside. This is similar to with-slots and with-accessors. I think the code you wrote should look like: (with-import (class-direct-slots) 'clos (class-direct-slots (find-class 'test-class)))

Comment: @claytontstanley: why not? p1::class-direct-slots is a legal function name. WITH-SLOTS or WITH-ACCESSORS does have no problems dealing with such names. My example shows that nested WITH-IMPORT where one function is generated and then another tries to use it is not possible with your macro. Remember: if you deal with Common Lisp macros, you are not only writing a construct that is used by an end user in a simple way (whose limits you would have to document and/or check), but everything can also be part of much more complicated code which is generated by other code (-> macros).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import` with a list of qualified symbols (i.e. `package:symbol` or `package::symbol`) you want to import and then `unintern` them.